# VF pie chart display percentage

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I've created a pie chart in a Visualforce page. Is there a way to show each wedge's percentage?

Answer (score 1):

There is `labelfield` in `piechart` which you can use to show percentage label or any other information.

```
<apex:pieSeries tips="true" dataField="piedata" labelField="name"/>
```

`name` is the wrapper class variable referenced to show count/text for each chart.

Alternatively you can use `<apex:chartTips/>`

```
 <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
```

Comment: The options you mentioned show the text and count, and I would like to show only the percentage amount of each wedge

Comment: @Neta You will have to calculate percentage yourself and show it as count.

Answer (score 0):

It can be displayed on chart easily you can refer this link ..

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I calculated the percentage myself and displayed it with chartTips:

apex:chartTips height="20" width="120" valueField="xxxPercent"

Comment: Neha seems like Ashwani's suggestion helped you. If so, do upvote and mark it as the answer.